# How to show panel with dynamic content (HTML) in it

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to show drop-down menu with HTML content in it when the user presses my addon's button on browser's toolbar.

It seems that I need to use [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel) as suggested in the documentation but the problem is that my content is dynamic and can change over time while addon works. AFAIK `panel` can only work with predefined HTML files and change its content via scripts provided by `contentScript` property, but even then it is clearly stated in the documentation that it can lead to the non-approved addon:

> Warning: Unless your content script is extremely simple and consists
>   only of a static string, don't use contentScript: if you do, you may
>   have problems getting your add-on approved on AMO.
>
> Instead, keep the script in a separate file and load it using contentScriptFile. This makes your code easier to maintain, secure,
>   debug and review.

What can I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph you quote refers to defining complex scripts inline with the `contentScript` parameter. If you use `contentScriptFile` to load the script which then modifies the HTML that should be fine.

Comment: I can't put this code to the separate .js file because it needs access to an add-on array. Or is there any way to access it from the content script?

Comment: you can use message-passing via the [port API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port).